# Integral group ring of the free group on two generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, free-groups, group-rings

I know that the integral group ring $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z]$ of $\mathbb Z$ is described as the ring of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb Z[t^{\pm}]$. I'm asking if there is a known description of the integral group ring $\mathbb Z[F_2]$ of the free group on two generators. Thank you for your help!.

Comment: This "free group ring" is a topic in the article [Free group rings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08196), but I don't see where they describe the structure more concretely. See also [this book](https://bookstore.ams.org/conm-66).

Comment: It  is unclear what do you mean by a "known description," beyond the definition.

Answer (score 2):

The description is the same as the $\,\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z]\,$ case you gave
except the polynomials have **non commuting** variables. Thus the group ring
$\,\mathbb Z[F_2]\,$ is described by $\,\mathbb Z[t^{\pm},u^{\pm}]\,$ where the two
variables $\,t\,$ and $\,u\,$ do not commute.

Comment: True, but this is just a restatement of the definition, except, more sloppily since the same can be said about the group ring of any 2-generated noncommutative group.

Comment: No, because in a two generated group, you could have extra relations. Take $G$ to be the Klein group, for example.  For $F_2$, you have no extra relations apart the obvious ones and you really get the polynomial Laurent ring in two noncommuting variables.